# Compiler for custom cpu architecture

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, cpu, microcontroller

Is there a tool that will convert C to assembly that will run on Windows?

The cpu architecture (8 bit and 16 bit) is in-house meaning that it has it own instruction set.

The C compiler should use our in-house assembly language. The language is not based on `x86` nor `ARM`. I can not provide too many further details because it is company's Intellectual Property.

Comment: So let me get this straight: You want to cross-compile some C code to an in-house 8/16-bit custom cpu architecture and you want to do it with public compilers that have no idea what your system is? There are lots of different assembly languages, so you'll have to be more specific. Can your custom cpu architecture run x86 assembly? ARM?

Comment: the assembly language is in-house and it is not base on x86 or arm.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to learn one of the open source Compilers which are using replaceable backend for their code generation. Gcc, and CLang, might be a good starting point.

Comment: http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vbcc/ is another one, less pain than gcc and llvm.

Comment: @dwelch [SDCC - Small Device C Compiler](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/) seems to be another maintained retargettable compiler. Google query: `microcontroller embedded 8bit c compiler` might reveal other candidates

Comment: right, forgot, sdcc is another and it caters to 8/16 bit micros...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Virginia, there are "tools to convert C to assembly" on Windows.  GCC comes to mind; likewise MS Visual Studio.

I'm sure this isn't what you want, since the off-the-shelf versions for Windows tend to generate x86 object code.  It sounds like you want a compiler for a special not-x86 instruction set.

Given that you have not provided any details, there's no way for anybody to respond if such a compiler already exists.

In the absence of such detail, all one can do is offer you generic advice.   It is possible to configure GCC to generate code for relatively arbitrary instruction sets.  It isn't a walk in the park to do this, but it has been done for many different instruction sets.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry to not providing you further detail because its a company IP ... and I hope you understand, and yes no such compiler exists. so you are saying that I can compile GCC in MS Visual Studio ?

Comment: GCC will self-compile; for Windows, get the Cygwin tools (cygwin.org) which include a working x86 GCC compiler.   You can also get the sources for GCC from http://www.gnu.org/software/software.html.   From there, you can use the GCC compiler to compile modified sources to GCC.   You then modify the sources to match your instruction set.   I have no specific experience with this, but people have been doing it for the last 20 years.   It is not practical to modify the MS C compilers.